# Which criterion do we use for the convergence of the sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I want to check as for the convergence the following sequences:

$$\left( \left( 1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}\right), \left( \left( 1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n}\right), \left( \left( 1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{n}\right), \left( \left( 1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^{n}\right).$$

Do we use the criterion that every monotone and bounded sequence converges? Or do we use an other criterion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each case, it is easy to determine whether the sequence converge or not using the fact that$$(\forall y\in\mathbb{R}):\lim_{x\to+\infty}\left(1+\frac yx\right)^x=e^y.$$

Comment: How can we use this? In our case the power is different from the denominator...

Comment: For instance, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=e$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\right)^n=\infty$.

Comment: Ah I see. For the second sequence, we have that $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \left( 1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^n=\lim_{n \to +\infty} \sqrt[n]{\left( 1+\frac{1}{n^2}\right)^{n^2}}$. Can we here use the equality? @JoseCarlosSantos

Comment: Yes, we can. From what you wrote, it follows that the sequence converges to $1$.

Comment: How do we deduce that the sequence converges to $1$ ? Can we pass the limit inside the root? :/ @JoseCarlosSantos

Comment: Let $a_n=\left(1+\frac1{n^2}\right)^{n^2}$. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=e$, you have $1\leqslant a_n\leqslant 4$ if $n$ is large enough. But then $1\leqslant\sqrt[n]{a_n}\leqslant\sqrt[n]4$. Now, apply the squeeze theorem.

Comment: I got it. For the third sequence, we have that $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \left( 1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n=\lim_{n \to +\infty} \left( \left( 1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{\sqrt{n}}=\lim_{n \to +\infty} e^{\sqrt{n}}=+\infty$. Is this right? If so, does it hold that $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \left( 1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^n=\lim_{n \to +\infty} \left( \lim_{n \to +\infty} \left( 1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \right)^{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{\sqrt{n}}$ ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Nice. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

There exists $\,N\in\Bbb N\; $ s.t. for $\;n>N\;$ :

$$2\le\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\le3\implies 2^n\le\left(1+\frac1n\right)^{n^2}\le3^n$$

As before, for $\;n>M\;$ :

$$2\le\left(1+\frac1{n^2}\right)^{n^2}\le3\implies\sqrt[n]2\le\left(1+\frac1{n^2}\right)^n\le\sqrt[n]3$$

and etc. Apply the squeeze theorem and do the other cases

Comment: I see, thank you :)